# Javascript Asynchronous Function Chaining

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, promise, rsvp.js

I have a set of JavaScript functions on a Node server that are making HTTP requests to an external API. I'm trying to chain them. My HTTP request function returns a promise, so I've been trying to utilize .then().

```
var x = function(id){
    //Passes a URL and the ID provided and returns a promise
    return callAPI(url, id)
}

var y = function(id){
    //Same deal. Different URL, but calls a URL with an ID and returns a promise.
    return allAPI(url, id)
}

var z = function(id){
   var result = [];
   x(id).then(function(data){
       var promises = data.body.ids.map(function(id){
          return y(id);
       });
       RSVP.all(promises).then(function(){
          console.log('Promises finished') //this never runs
       });
   });
}
```

I read that forEach is synchronous, but if you're doing async things in the forEach there is no guarantee it will return correctly.  I think that the result array is being populated, I am just returning it at the wrong time?  But I am not sure where/how I can return it after all the promises have been fulfilled. Thoughts?

*edit* Adding the function that creates the promises. Maybe I'm doing that wrong?

```
var callAPI = function(url, query){
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        su.get(url)
            .query(query)
            .on('error', function(){
                reject(this);
            })
            .end(function(res){
                resolve(res);
            });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

This uses the SuperAgent HTTP framework. If I do a console.log on the returned promise, everything about it is undefined? But the functions that use callAPI still work? And I can chain them with .then still? Maybe I've missed something.

Comment: `return Promise.all(result)` and `return` the `.then` chain so you can hook on it later.

Comment: I added the callAPI definition that returns the promise.  Any idea if I'm doing that incorrectly?  If I create an array of promises and then use RSVP.all(promises), the .then never runs. Thoughts?

Comment: Hm, no, that should work. Maybe one of the promises is rejected?

Comment: So, fun tip: RSVP was the problem. I switched out RSVP with Bluebird and everything worked perfectly. I didn't even have to change any syntax (aside from anywhere I referenced RSVP). This was weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed RSVP and used Bluebird instead. For whatever reason, RSVP.all() was never firing even when all of the promises were fulfilled. I switched to Bluebird and everything worked as expected.

Comment: In that case, you should open an issue at RSVP, and include a complete reproducible example in your bug report.